# M2: How to add a <meta> tag on selected products?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to add a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />` tag on selected products. In Magento 1, this is what the custom layout update on the product edit is for, so I could just `reference` head and use `action` to do that.
In Magento 2, however, it seems that I'm unable to do that. Although the same Custom Layout Update product attribute still exists in M2 and I can use `referenceContainer`, I'm unable to use `referenceBlock`, or `<head>`, so I don't really know how to proceed with this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, I'd rather try avoid having to write a separate module just for achieving this goal if possible.